# extracting values matching timestamps by a new set of timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

[sample table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/larCb.png)

i am trying to look up corresponding commodity prices from columns(CU00.SHF,AU00.SHF,SC00.SHF,I8888.DCE  C00.DCE), with a new set of timestamps, the dates of which are 32 days later than the dates in column 'history_date'.

i tried .loc and .at in a loop to extract the matching values with below functions:

```
latest_day = data.iloc[data.shape[0] - 1, 0].date()

def next_trade_day(x):
    x = pd.to_datetime(x).date() #imported is_workday funtion requires datetime type
    while True:
        if is_workday(x + timedelta(32)) != False:
            break
            return (pd.Timestamp((x + timedelta(32))))
        if is_workday(x + timedelta(32)) == False:
            x = x + timedelta(1)
    return pd.Timestamp(x + timedelta(32))

def end_price(x):
    x = pd.Timestamp(x)
    if x <= latest_day:
        return data.at[x,'CU00.SHF']
    if x > latest_day:
        return'None'
    return data.at[x,'CU00.SHF']
```

but it always gives
KeyError: Timestamp('2023-02-03 00:00:00')

any idea how should i achieve the target?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want work datetime:

1. convert column datetime
2. check date converted, use filte

   ```
    pd.to_datetime(df['your column'],errors='ignore') 
    df.loc[df.['your column'] > 'your-date' ]
   ```

if work both, then check your full code.

Comment: thanks, but i tried converting everthing to datetime but python gives the keyerror nonetheless

Comment: tri only filter? df filter  df.loc[df.['your column'] > 'your-date' ], if it works

Comment: nah still no luck, this gives me ''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 146, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 49, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: datetime.date(2023, 2, 3). i am guessing this is not a type problem maybe?

Comment: As far as I understand this is not a code problem.

Comment: indeed, there is an innate problem under the hood with my excel data. now everything is working fine. thanks bro.

Comment: Very good. you will learn many things at the same time while working.